# Is it possible to use VirtualBox Guest Additions to manage a REAL machine?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have already used VirtualBox Guest Additions with virtual machines successfully, and I just love it. I was just wondering if I can use it to control a REAL machine, having the two separate taskbars and managing the windows seamlessly.

Is it possible, or I am just dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, it just hasn't been put into practice yet as far as I know. For managing separate machines people typically use remote desktop software such as RDP or VNC. If you want seamless integration (at least, from Linux to Windows) you can use [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) to run Linux applications over X11 forwarding:

[image]

You may also want to look into [Citrix](http://citrix.com/lang/English/home.asp) XenApp.

[image]

Comment: Ok, my question was not clear enough. I understand it IS possible, what I am really asking is whether the software is ready to do this right now. I did some digging, but found nothing about it. I tried "Synergy+" to handle both machines, but the lack of CTRL+ALT+DEL emulation and not being able to use the two monitors seamlessly drove me off.

Comment: You got it. Synergy+ is more of a software-based KVM solution. It doesn't allow any sort of seamless of programs across the machines. To answer your question in that regard, no, there is no Virtualbox Guest Addition that works for real machine integration. HTH.